# Upgraded to Mercurial 1.7 client, getting abort: requirement '<html>' not supported

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I think it's a config error based on similar, but not identical answers to errors I found such as requirement 'fncache' not supported.

No idea where this is coming from, but it started happening AFTER the upgrade.

Comment: *What* did you upgrade? Just the client? Or the server version as well? Also, what command are you invoking that gives you that error message? push? pull? commit? log?

Comment: Do you have a file named "requirements" or "requires" in the .hg directory of your repository? Can you try opening it in a text editor and see what the contents are?

Comment: I upgraded my client only. I opened the requires file and there's nothing like html in there.

Comment: Can you post the requires file on both client / server end?

Answer (score 0):

This is usually a problem with the server setup. It means the server does not return the expected answer.

Are you using static-http? (and please add the command line you are using when you get the error).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is an old hg executable in your path. The error message comes when a client tries to acces a local repository which is created by a higher hg version.